# tag issue with map view package in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-mapview

Hello I found an issue with map view package

package ref: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view

issue ref :https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/134

I think I can get around the problem.

The problem is :

1- when I call first time map(), tags are OK

2- when I push other page -> go back -> launch map() -> tags are removed

3- on android studio , If reload ( Maj+F10 => Run) Tag are OK

Solution :

Simulate the reload when I back to the first page, it's possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Is your First Page extends Stateful Widgets ?

Comment: Yes it's Stateful